# How to invoke a machine with context of the machine that invokes that machine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, xstate

Firstly, [here](https://stately.ai/viz/2c965f17-f447-4bbe-8469-4cd7072adc46#)’s the code. I need to fix.

---

Basically, there are two machines:

- `currentStateMachine`:

  - currently, I want to change the state manually (running `send` commands) once a second based on the real state;
  - later, it might be better to run a callback function based on which the state would change, however, currently I have no idea if it could work like that;
  - I use `context` to store the current timestamp and the state;
  - PROBLEM: how to invoke `intervalsMachine` with the `context` of `currentStateMachine`?
  - QUESTION: will `currentStateMachine` wait for `invoke` completion before accepting another state event? Or will it wait until the state is processed and only after that a new event is processed?
- `intervalsMachine`:

  - it creates an interval from the current states whenever a new state is received;
  - it uses `context` to store `startTime` of the interval, its `length` and the state during this interval;
  - the interval calculation is simplified for demostration, in will be much more complex.

---

#### TL;DR

1. How to invoke `intervalsMachine` (invoked machine) with the `context` of `currentStateMachine` (machine that invokes `intervalsMachine`)?
2. Will `currentStateMachine` wait for `invoke` completion before accepting another state event? Or will it wait until the state is processed and only after that a new event is processed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data` property with `invoke` to specify context to be taken from the parent.

```js
const timerMachine = createMachine({
  id: 'timer',
  context: {
    duration: 1000 // default duration
  }
  /* ... */
});

const parentMachine = createMachine({
  id: 'parent',
  initial: 'active',
  context: {
    customDuration: 3000
  },
  states: {
    active: {
      invoke: {
        id: 'timer',
        src: timerMachine,
        // Deriving child context from parent context
        data: {
          duration: (context, event) => context.customDuration
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/communication.html#invoking-with-context

Another option is you can use the `(ctx, evt) => ...` pattern for the `src` option.